# Can core.match be used to add type information for an object?

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.typed

When I work in Scala, I like that I can pattern match on type and the type-checker will make use of that type:

```
val x : Any = "boop"
x match {
  case y : String => do-something-stringy(y);
  case z : Int => .... etc
}
```

I know in core.typed, a conditional will help the type checker to resolve the exact type. I tried to replicate this using core.match:

```
(ann do-something-stringy [String -> String])
(defn do-something-stringy [message]
  (str "Hello " message))


;; Doesn't work
(ann do-things [Object -> String])
(defn do-things [foo]
  (match [(type foo)]
         [String] (do-something-stringy foo)
         :else "Nope"))
```

This fails with an error:

> Function do-something-stringy could not be applied to arguments:
>
> Domains:
>     String
>
> Arguments:
>     Object
>
> Ranges:
>     String
>
> with expected type:
>     String

Is there a way to get this to work using core.match?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try dispatching on `class` rather than `type`. core.typed has no real support for `type` due to its weirdness around metadata.